# How to enter a tab character in vim with SuperTab plugin enabled?

Tags: vim

How to enter a tab character in vim with SuperTab plugin enabled?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've not used this extension myself, but I would guess that ^V-Tab might work.  ^V in general can be used in insert mode to insert a literal keystroke instead of whatever that key is mapped to do.  So you type Control-V, then hit whatever key or key combo you want to insert literally.

Comment: In the `^V` docs at `:help i_^v`: "Note: When CTRL-V is mapped (e.g., to paste text) you can often use CTRL-Q instead." See `:help i_^q`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to simulate pressing `<tab>` as if SuperTab were not installed (i.e. you want to insert a tab that respects your `:set expandtab` settings) then press Ctrl-Tab.

`^V-<tab>` inserts a literal tab. If you have `:set expandtab` enabled then this might not be what you want, because it inserts a real Tab character, not a series of spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the indent functionality by typing `>>` which depending on your indent settings would use a tab character.